# Show Product based on the package

Tags: php

I want to show the object (item) based on its package. With the php code I have now, I got the result like this:

```
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Package           Price            Deskription        Prodcut    
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   => 2kg             20                sdasdsada          
   => 4kg             40                sdasdsada         PRODCUT ONE 
   => 6kg             60                sdasdsada          
   => 8kg             80                sdasdsada          
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   => 2kg             20                sdasdsada          
   => 4kg             40                sdasdsada         PRODCUT TWO 
   => 6kg             60                sdasdsada          
   => 8kg             80                sdasdsada
```

`=>` is a dropdown

However, what I want the result is like this:

```
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Package           Price            Deskription        Etc    
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
                      20                sdasdsada         
   => 2,4,6,8kg       40                sdasdsada         PRODCUT ONE 
                      60                sdasdsada         
                      80                sdasdsada         
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
                      20                sdasdsada         
   => 2,4,6,8kg       40                sdasdsada         PRODCUT TWO 
                      60                sdasdsada         
                      80                sdasdsada
```

PLEASE HELP

```
<?php 

include ("config.php");
        $results = $mysqli->query
          ("    
            SELECT product_package.id,
                   product_package.size,
                   product_package.price, 
                   product_package.description, 
                   product_package.image,

                   product_list.code, 
                   product_list.name                

            FROM product_package
            LEFT JOIN product_list ON product_list.code = product_package.code"
          );      
        $orders = array();     
        $html = '';     
        if ($results) {
            while($obj = $results->fetch_object()) {
                $orders[$obj->code][$obj->size]  = array(
                    'code' => $obj->code, 
                    'size' => $obj->size, 
                    'name' => $obj->name, 
                    'price' => $obj->price, 
                    'description' => $obj->description, 
                    'image' => $obj->image);
            }

            $html .= '<table width="100%" id="orderHistoryTable"><div>';
            $html .= '<td>package_size</td>';
            $html .= '<td>price</td>';
            $html .= '<td>description</td>';
            $html .= '<td>image</td>';
            $html .= '<td>name</td>';

            foreach ($orders AS $order_id => $order) {
            $orderCount = count($order);
                $html .= '<tbody id="ttbody">';
                $row = 1;

                foreach ($order AS $item => $data) {

                    if ($row > 1) { $html .= '</tr><tr>'; }

                        $html .= '<td>';

                        //HELP ME HERE
                        $html .= '<select>';
                        $html .= '<option>'.$data['size'].'</option>';                          
                        $html .= '</select>';
                        //HELP ME HERE

                        $html .= '</td>';
                        $html .= '<td>' . $data['price'] . '</td>';
                        $html .= '<td>'. $data['description'] . '</td>';
                        $html .= '<td>' . $data['image'] . '</td>';

                    if ($row == 1)
                      $html .= '<td rowspan="' . $orderCount . '">' . $data['name'] . '</td>';
                      $row++;
                }
        }
                $html .= '</div>';
                $html .= '<tbody>';

            $html .= '</table>';
        } 
        echo $html;
?>
```